# How to load select-options in Angular through code

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

I am trying to build a generic form in Angular whose data is going to be fetched at runtime. A form can have fields which may reference to other models. That's why I am trying to fetch the data and then create the options at runtime in the TypeScript code instead of the HTML template. The issue I am having is that the 'select' is not populating its options. I am not sure what I am missing here? This is how my component code looks like:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Input, OnChanges, QueryList, SimpleChanges, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { NzSelectComponent, NzSelectOptionInterface } from 'ng-zorro-antd/select';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-wrapper',
  templateUrl: './select-wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-wrapper.component.css']
})
export class SelectWrapperComponent implements  AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const selectLists = document.getElementsByTagName('select')
    let selectComponent : HTMLSelectElement = selectLists[0];
    
    if(selectComponent && this.data)
    {
      this.data.forEach(element => {
        selectComponent.options.add(new Option(element.name, element.id.toString()));
      }
      );
      console.log(selectComponent.options);
      
    }
  }
 
  @Input() data = [];
}
```

And this the component's HTML template:

```
<select></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Build the options in your template instead. Something like the following

template:

```
<select>
     <option *ngFor="element of data" value="element.id">
          {{ element.name }} 
     </option>
</select>
```

component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-wrapper',
  templateUrl: './select-wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-wrapper.component.css']
})
export class SelectWrapperComponent implements  AfterViewInit {
  @Input() data = [];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I also mentioned that it is dynamic form with all the input components created at runtime through a database. That's why doing it through a template is not an option for me. I already know the standard way of data binding in Angular. Thank you in any case.